# Custom metric is unable to display in Custom report after data import in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, universal-analytics

I have created custom metric named as "OrderValue" with scope type as a Hit and formatting type as an integer. The goal is to upload this metric value in GA against custom dimension.
I have created One Custom Data Set and two .csv files are uploaded with given schema.

```
ga:dimension2,ga:metric3
864364158.1408537764,90
1300617200.1408542207,92
1877924069.1408542623,93
1907422855.1408542517,94
402600978.1408541946,95
53720731.1408542050,96
976341314.1408542697,97
1172524593.1408595931,98
188551773.1408595795,99
322956916.1408614851,100
1620242950.1408616228,101
2109954542.1408615793,102
```

Both csv files contain valid data, but in Custom reporting, The ordervalue is not reflected. Please note that I am planning to load the integer value in ga:metric3 against ga:dimension2. Is there some restriction on the type of values that go under custom dimensions. The value I have is “864364158.1408537764” which I think can be treated as string by GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to ensure to get [Data Import](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/integration-upload) to work properly.

1. The file must be uploaded **before** the hits are sent. The data gets joined at processing time.
2. And ensure that the key metric, ga:dimension1 matches the values your are sending the hits.

   ```
   ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');

   // Set value for custom dimension at index 1.
   ga('set', 'dimension1', '864364158.1408537764');

   // Send the custom dimension value with a pageview, file already uploaded.
   ga('send', 'pageview');
   ```

To answer your final question, the values of the custom dimensions are treated as strings, so there is no problem sending '864364158.1408537764'.